# Using EntityManagerFactory, Persistence Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, bean-validation

I run in to a problem while trying to use EntityManagerFactory instead of SessionFactory. The model is annotation based and is tested with SessionFactory.

Here is the stack trace

```
   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:195)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:244)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ethiopianMarketdb] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:378)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
        at org.dejach.marketApi.AdministratorApiTest.(AdministratorApiTest.java:12)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1704)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1654)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1445)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1519)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1100)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:282)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:366)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:118)
        ... 35 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:31)
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
        at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:380)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:109)
        ... 40 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 45 more
```

```
    package org.dejach.marketApi;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;

    import org.dejach.Address;
    import org.dejach.Role;
    import org.junit.Test;

    public class AdministratorApiTest {
        static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "ethiopianMarketdb" );
        static EntityManager em= emf.createEntityManager();
        MarketApi marketApi = new MarketApi();

       @Test
        public void testView() {
        }

        @Test
        public void testAdd() throws MarketApiExceptions {
            MarketApi.setEm(em);
            Address address = new Address();
            address.setCityName("Addis Ababa");
            address.setCountryName("Ethiopia");
            address.setEmail("dgdoorvan@yahoo.com");
            address.setFixedLinePhoneNo("None");
            address.setHouseNo("905");
            address.setMobilePhoneNo("+251912978393");
            address.setStreetName("Kotebe");


            AdministratorApi administratorApi = new AdministratorApi();
            administratorApi.setAdministratorAddress(address);
            administratorApi.setAdministratorId("Admin ID");
            administratorApi.setPassword("DGrekik377");
            administratorApi.setRole(Role.dejach.name());   
            administratorApi.setFirstName("Dejazmach");
            administratorApi.setLastName("Getachew");
            administratorApi.setUserName("User Dejach");
            administratorApi.setStatus(true);

            this.marketApi.addAdministrator(administratorApi);
        }

        @Test
        public void testDelete() {
        }

        @Test
        public void testUpdate() {
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thankyou, but I use maven and I have it there as a dependency.

Comment: Read the message.  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider  NOTHING to do with JPA API. Everything to do with not having bean-validation API in your CLASSPATH

Comment: Thankyou, I found the answer on the duplicate page.The problem was not caused by not including hibernate-validator rather it was that I shouldn't have used validation-api along with hibernate-validator.